# Need help retrieving authorized user information Flutter Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have implemented in my flutter application Authentication via Firebase by login and password.

I also connected to a Firestore table with user data.

I only need to show the authenticated user's data by their ID, which are assigned to the other data tables.

How to link e.g. Users id: 1 with Tasks User id:1 ?

[image]

[image]

home_page.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loginui/read_data/get_user_name.dart';

class MyTaskPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTaskPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyTaskPage> createState() => _MyTaskPageState();
}

class _MyTaskPageState extends State<MyTaskPage> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  // document IDs
  List<String> docIDs = [];

  // get docIDs
  Future getDocId() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('tasks')
        .orderBy('name', descending: true)
        // .where('age', isGreaterThan: 44)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
              print(document.reference);
              docIDs.add(document.id);
            }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[200],
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              });
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.logout),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getDocId(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: docIDs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: GetUserName(documentId: docIDs[index]),
                          tileColor: Colors.grey[200],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

get_user_name.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;

  GetUserName({required this.documentId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // get the collection
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks');
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text(
            '${data['name']}',
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            softWrap: true,
          );
        }
        return Text('Loading...');
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added my code

Answer (score 1):

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
if (_auth.currentUser != null) {
  // user is signed in
  final uid = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
  final userData = await _firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get();
  final taskData = await _firestore.collection('tasks').doc(uid).get();

  // handle the data
}
```